# bad_alloc() when recursively producing combinations and storing to vector

Tags: c++, memory, pthreads, heap-memory, stack-memory

**Overview**:
I am trying to produce combinations from a set of characters, with a specific starting character, where each combination is of a certain length within a range. For example if my set of characters is {A,B,C,D} and starting prefix 'A' then my combinations for lengths 1 through 3 are: A, AA, AB, AC, AD, AAA, AAB, AAC, AAD,....,ADD.

**Problem**: I produce each combination recursively. The problem is when I try to store combinations to a vector for a larger set of characters for range of lengths 1 through 8 (which I obviously understand are many combinations) I get a bad_alloc core dumped error. My understanding is that this means I ran out of memory (possibly due to my vector being full). I want to try allocating this vector to the heap and keeping it global. Below is my current code before attempting to modify:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

#define SIZE_SET 15 // sizeof set below, set of characters to create permutations from
char set[] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O'};            
void ProducePerms(vector<string>&, string, const int, const int);

int main(){

    // Timing program run time
    clock_t t1, t2;
    t1 = clock();

    cout << "Starting time" << endl;

    vector<string> perms; // Stores permutations
    string start_prefix = "B"; // All permutations of lengths 1-8 begin with this prefix
    int length = 8; // Maximum length of permutation

    // Produce lengths 1-8 permutations starting with prefix
    for(int l = 0; l < length; l++){
        ProducePerms(perms, start_prefix, SIZE_SET, l);
    }

    // End run time
    t2 = clock();
    cout << "\nTime elapsed: " << (t2-t1)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}

void ProducePerms(vector<string>& vec, string prefix, const int n, const int length){
    if(length == 0){
       vec.push_back(prefix);
    }
    else{
       if(length == 1){
           for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
               vec.push_back(prefix + set[j]);
            }
        }
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                ProducePerms(vec, prefix + set[i], n, length - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also if anyone has any suggestions on how I can adapt this to using pthreads that would be helpful. I am currently thinking of creating pthreads to compute combinations for a certain length.

Comment: Have you calculated how many possible combinations your result would have? It seems likely that you are actually running out of memory.

Comment: What is your purpose in generating these sequences?

Comment: string of 8 symbols with 16 symbol values would produce 16 ^ 8 combinations. Hoping that small string optimization takes place you will need a buffer at least of 16 ^ 8 * 24 = 103079215104 bytes ≈ 100 Gb

Comment: @NeilButterworth I am trying to adapt this to an assignment I have. I basically have to take all possible combinations of a set of ASCII characters, hash them using some cryptography function (I'm using MD5 which basically converts any string into a 32 character string) and then see if any of these hashed combinations matches the hash of a string I chose. I have to accomplish this using pthreads so my approach is to create pthreads for each element in my set of characters to parallelize producing the combinations and hashing. Clearly it is not efficient and memory is an issue

Comment: Right now you seem to be brute forcing the assignment. Is it possible to devise a different approach?

Comment: @TrebuchetMS I’m supposed to brute force. I believe the proper approach is to divide the total number of combinations into equal number of threads. This is the best way to evenly distribute the workload. However, I still don’t see how this is good when (using my recursive function to compute combinations) one thread is producing a combination of length 3 and another is doing a length 8